# Does the order of samples taken affect the probability of getting a certain value?

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is asking what is the probability of taking two samples and having the first one being shorter than 20 and the second one being larger than 25 based on the given density curve

The density curve shows that the P(length< 20) = 0.35 and that P(length>25) = 0.24.

So would you just multiply the two probabilities together, giving 0.084? Or do you have to factor in order somehow?

What if the question says that order doesn't matter, but one has to have length < 20 and one has to have length > 25? All I can think of doing is multiplying them together again and getting the same P = 0.084. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure in the first problem is correct. Your answer does take order into account, it finds the probability of **first** is short and **second** is long.

For the second problem, you are missing the fact that one short one long can occur in **two** orders, SL and LS. So the probability for the second problem is twice the probability for the first.